# How to make an application command?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way I can make a command such as **-apply** and the bot sends them a DM starting that you've started your application! Then it asks a question, and the person answers, then it goes to the second question, person answers, then they can say submit or react with a check to send their answers and it sends all of their answers and the questions to a channel I specify in my server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can use the [`message.collector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector) methods. Here is a nice [example](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) that partially fulfills your needs.

Comment: Your question has a lot of nuances and implementation options, so answering it specifically is too laborious.